# How to create Reminder for some time like Remind me in 30 mins in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, push-notification, uilocalnotification

Hi I working on a reminder application.

I need to display a reminder alert after some particular time.

**But not** at the time we have set in date picker.

*Just like I have a button 'Remind in 10 Mins'*

```
-(IBAction)ReminderClick:(id)sender
{
}
```

***When user press the button , After 10 mins it needs to display an alert.***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use UILocalNotification for this Function
Code is look like

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        NSDate *date1=[fire dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
        notifyAlarm.fireDate = date1;
        notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        //notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notifyAlarm.repeatInterval =NSWeekCalendarUnit ;
        notifyAlarm.soundName =soundString;
        notifyAlarm.alertBody =snoozeBody;
        notifyAlarm.userInfo=snoozeDict;
        //notifyAlarm.alertLaunchImage=@"in.png";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
```

and You can follow thos tutorial for this
http://www.icodeblog.com/tag/uilocalnotification/

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/

http://www.iostipsandtricks.com/ios-local-notifications-tutorial/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcVoq488-XI

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UILocalNotificataion for this

Comment: this answer is not concrete. I think he already knows it. You should provide specific answer here.